# How to Toggle video recording in Twilio

Tags: twilio, video-recording, twilio-video

I am trying to add a Toggle recording feature into my web application,
Using Twilio Client version 2.0 and Generating token via Java Server side code.
Toggle(just to be clear)-> Being able to pause/start recording when a call is already underway.

Question : How to implement toggle recording feature in Twilio, If that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of now, Pause/Start video recording on a video call is not possible.**

Response from Twilio support:

> Thanks for reaching out to us! At this time, pausing and resuming a recording isn't possible. This is a feature we're looking to add in the future, but I don't have a specific date to share on when that will be available. I'll add your ticket to the feature request so that we can accurately set a priority for implementing it. Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Is there any update on the same from Twilio Niyas ?

Comment: @NageshTripathi Still No!. But Tokbox has a similar feature - https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/web/archiving/